# Laravel: How to count the number of new students registered and the number of online students per month?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to count the number of new students registered and the number of online students per month. I want output like this:

**Required Output**:

```
"month" "total"  
--------------
"Jan"   "0"
"Feb"   "0"
"Mar"   "0"
"Apr"   "0"
"May"   "0"
"Jun"   "22"
"Jul"   "0"
"Aug"   "30"
"Sep"   "0"
"Oct"   "0"
"Nov"   "0"
"Dec"   "0"
```

But the result returned is:
**Output**:

```
"month" "total"  
--------------  
"Jun"   "22"
"Aug"   "30"
```

Here is my code

```php
$getTotalOnl = Member::select(
    DB::raw('IFNULL(count(id),0) as count'),
    DB::raw('YEAR(updated_at) year, MONTH(updated_at) month')
     )->whereBetween('updated_at', [$from, $to])->groupby('year','month')->get()->toArray();
     dd($getTotal);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public function register() {
  $month = 12
  totalStudents = [];

  for($i = $month; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $students = Student::whereMonth('created_at', $i)->get();
    totalStudents[] = $i . '=' . $students->count(); 
  }

  dd($totalStudents);
}
```

`$i` represents the date if `$i = 01` its represents as `january` you can make that logic